# css script working but js script not working in Django

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, backend

My index.css script located at **Project/static/css/index.css** is working fine and effect is seen in index.html page. But window alert from index.js script is not seen.

Since .css script is working fine, I assume that there is no issue with settings.py so problem might be with linking. I tried two alternatives:

```
<script src="{% static "/jss/index.js" %}"
type="text/javascript"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" href="{%
static "jss/index.js"%}">
```

Both not working.

Html page: **Project/templates/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{%load static%}
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <script src="{% static "jss/index.js" %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/index.css"%}">

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Base Html</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {%block body%}
    {%endblock%}
  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript Page: **Project/static/jss/index.js**

```
alert("Hello, Welcome to my page");
```

**settings.py**

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = '&cq=^n*t!55h)0c@3f+7*ilrvr$066)*n)&-8v6rokna4-yd30'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'App',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Project.wsgi.application'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS=[os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),]
```

Comment: Can you post the error from console in the browser

Comment: Thanks, console was showing error for commented lines in index.js file.